# Unable to remove image preview after click outside div or close button javascript PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on Php with jquery,
I have jquery Popup modal and right now i am displaying image preview,I want whenever
i click outside modal or click on close button(close_btn_t)then image should remove and click on
browse button selected image should display, how can i do this ?
Here is my code

```
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="preivew-right-bar">
                    <span class="previewpostimage"><img id="thumb" src="blob:https://xxxxxxxxx/0d865270-6aee-4873-8c4a-16a67273e3e6" style="display: none;"></span>
                        
                                    <span class="close_btn_t">
                                    
<button type="button" id="closebtn"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
 </span>
                    </div>
    </div>
```

I tried with following code

```
$('body').click(function (event) 
{
   if (
      event.target.matches(".button-close-modal") ||
      !event.target.closest(".modal-content")
    ) {
            $(".previewpostimage").html("");
            $('.previewpostimage').val('');
   }     
});
```

Comment: please share your jquery code you have tried so far.

Comment: @AqibJaved: updated my question now you can see my javascript code

Comment: you can use focusout jquery function